# Specify Initial Values for For Loop

Tags: python, loops

I am currently working on coding a recursive algorithm. I created functions similar to the one below with a lot of for loops.

```
def create_m_(y, m, theta, mc, theta_mc):
    for i in range (len(data[0])-1):   
        m = create_m(y)[i]
        theta = theta_m[i]
        mc = create_mc(y)[i-1]
        create_theta_mc[i-1] 
        m_ =  (m * theta_mc + mc * theta + m * mc)
        return m_
```

The only thing is: the initial values of mc and theta_mc that will start the loop are not calculated using the formulas in the function (these initial values are specific cases). How do I got about setting the loop to specify the first values of mc and theta_mc?

EDIT:
Can I do this?

```
def create_m_(y, m, theta, mc, theta_mc):
    for i in range (len(data[0])-1): 
        if i == 1:
            m = m_2
            theta = theta_m_2
        else:        
            m = create_m(y)[i]
            theta = theta_m[i]
            mc = create_mc(y)[i-1]
            create_theta_mc[i-1] 
            m_ =  (m * theta_mc + mc * theta + m * mc)
        return m_
```

Comment: Your code doesn't make much sense.  The last line of your for loop is a return statement, so the loop is not a loop at all.  It will only be executed once.  And the first time the loop executes, i == 0 (not 1).  Please fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Just change the function

```
def create_m_(y, m, theta, mc, theta_mc)
```

to:

```
def create_m_(y, m, theta, mc=initial_value, theta_mc=initial_value)
```

When you call this function for the first time without specifying the value of `mc` or `theta-mc`, they will default to the initial value.